# What are the notify-keyspace-events in Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-boot

I started to setup spring project by following this [spring-boot article](https://spring.io/blog/2015/05/13/modularizing-the-client-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-vii). But suddenly application could not start successfully, instead I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at demo.UiApplication.main(UiApplication.java:29)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.setConfig(JedisConnection.java:618)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:170)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:113)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:131)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:200)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:285)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:184)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.configSet(Jedis.java:2797)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.setConfig(JedisConnection.java:616)
    ... 18 more
```

The main message is: `ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events`.

What does it mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about Redis keyspace notifications at: http://redis.io/topics/notifications

Regardless of what they actually are, it appears that your Redis server doesn't support them (e.g. < v2.8).

Comment: @Karthik : I am also getting the same exception : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177688/embedded-redis-cant-start

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation, you can turn notify-keyspace-events on in either your template or when you instantiate your listener:

In your template:

```
@Bean("basicKeyspaceTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<String, String> basicKeyspaceTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    
    RedisTemplate<String, String> template = new RedisTemplate<>();

    // Turn on Keyspace notifications
    RedisServerCommands cmd = connectionFactory.getConnection();
    cmd.setConfig("notify-keyspace-events", "KEA");

    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();

    return template;
}
```

Or when you create your listener:

```
    class RedisKeyspaceListener extends KeyspaceEventMessageListener{

    private KeyspaceEventMessageListener _listener;
    private String _key;

    public RedisKeyspaceListener(String key, RedisMessageListenerContainer _basicListenerContainer) {
        super(_basicListenerContainer);
        this._listener = this;
        _listener.setKeyspaceNotificationsConfigParameter("KEA");
        _listener.init();
        _log.info(String.format("Keyspace listener established for key %s", key));
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHandleMessage(Message message) {
        // TODO! Build filter and determine way to get key value(s) to sendTextMessage;
        _log.info(String.format("Keyspace event message from key %s -> message %s", _key, message.toString() ));
        MsgHandler.this.sendTextMessage(message.toString());
    }
}
```

For additional reference, my RedisListenerContainer:

```
@Component    
public class RedisListenerContainer {
        
    private static RedisMessageListenerContainer _basicListenerContainer;
    
        @Bean("basicListenerContainer")
        RedisMessageListenerContainer basicListenerContainer(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Error {
            RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
            container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            _basicListenerContainer = container;
            return container;
        }
    
        public static RedisMessageListenerContainer get_basicListenerContainer() {
            return _basicListenerContainer;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, Spring (and other sites) do not give a good example of implementing a basic keyspace notification.

What I found the hard way is that setKeyspaceNotificationsConfigParameters is the settings for the notifications, not a "filter" for keys or event types.

So, if you re-use your listener container, as you add keys, you will get a notification from **Every key** even though you only acted on a single key.

In other words, it's really not implemented like what Redis describes at https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/

Comment: Have you posted your sample code (project) any where? I am struck on a implementation same as this logic.

Comment: Example code that I used and the feature request to allow the selection of which type of events to receive: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/2757