# Embedded redis can't start - ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I am using the embedded-redis 0.6 version and spring-session-data-redis 1.0.1.RELEASE. After executing spring boot with mvn spring-boot:run command tomcat server starts but embedded redis immediately throws following exception (see full stack trace below):

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events

How can I resolve this issue?

My pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.kstyrc</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Full stack trace:

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at com.springbootapp.config.Application.main(Application.java:16)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:44)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.setConfig(JedisConnection.java:633)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.configure(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:63)
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:117)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:196)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.configSet(Jedis.java:2575)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.setConfig(JedisConnection.java:631)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error often happens in one of the two situations:

**The Redis Version is too old**

This seems like the most likely answer. From [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession.html#running-the-httpsession-sample-application):

> For the sample to work, you must install Redis 2.8+ on localhost and
>   run it with the default port (6379). Alternatively, you can update the
>   JedisConnectionFactory to point to a Redis server.

If you don't care about receiving events you can disable the keyspace notifications setup by [creating a ConfigureRedisAction Bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-redisoperationssessionrepository-sessiondestroyedevent):

```
@Bean
public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
    return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
}
```

or XML

```
<util:constant
    static-field="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP"/>
```

Alternatively, ensure you are running Redis 2.8+.

**Your Redis instance has Disabled or renamed the config Command**

This is unlikely the case with the embedded instance since will by default configuration. From the documentation:

> If you are using @EnableRedisHttpSession the SessionMessageListener
>   and enabling the necessary Redis Keyspace events is done
>   automatically. However, in a secured Redis enviornment the config
>   command is disabled. This means that Spring Session cannot configure
>   Redis Keyspace events for you. To disable the automatic configuration
>   add ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP as a bean.
>
> For example, Java Configuration can use the following:

```
@Bean
public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
    return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
}
```

or XML

```
<util:constant
    static-field="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP"/>
```

Comment: I am using the embedded redis configuration

Comment: Is there any new version available for embedded-redis configuration which will not require the NO OP setting , my pom.xml dependencies are listed down

Comment: Spring Session stopped using embedded Redis because it was not very stable in terms of modern versions and working on all OSs. I think your best bet is to switch to an external Redis instance.

Comment: From where to download the redis server for windows , Can I configure the redis instance where it will shift from internal to external redis instance

Comment: From Redis download page "The Redis project does not officially support Windows. However, the Microsoft Open Tech group develops and maintains this Windows port targeting Win64." https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis

You can use the Spring Environment abstraction to externalize the configuration for where Redis is pointing to. If you need help with this another question is likely necessary (please include if you are using JavaConfig, XML Config, or Spring Boot)

Comment: I am using the Spring boot, how this redis server runs on linux as the background process.

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: That means how the redis server starts in the background , how to keep it running as the background process.

Comment: Use "service redis-server start" https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/redis/redis-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin