# Startup error using Spring-boot-starter-data-redis on AWS using ssl

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

So, ran into an interesting issue today messing spring-boot-starter-data-rest. My use case is to store some data on redis with some expiration time so that it will be evicted as soon that time elapses. I got everything configured and works on my local redis without any issues. It becomes a problem when trying to work with it on AWS using secured connection (SSL) and is a sample error:

```
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
           at com.springbootapp.config.Application.main(Application.java:16)
           ... 6 more
   Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
           at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:44)
           at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisExceptionConverter.convert(JedisExceptionConverter.java:36)
           at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
           at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:37)
           at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.convertJedisAccessException(JedisConnection.java:210)
           at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.setConfig(JedisConnection.java:633)
           at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.configure(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:63)
           at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:167)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
           ... 22 more
   Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: notify-keyspace-events
           at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:117)
           at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:151)
           at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:205)
           at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:297)
           at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:196)
           at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.configSet(Jedis.java:2575)
           at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnection.setConfig(JedisConnection.java:631)
           ... 26 more
```

I am not using `@EnabledRedisSession` and it dependencies as I have not need for it.

It turns out that most of the examples out there are geared towards that.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177688/embedded-redis-cant-start](http://www.example.com/)!

I added spring redis session dependency and tried

```
@Bean
public static ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
    return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
}
```

`@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_DEMAND)`

changed that to on_demand I get the following error.

My redisContainer shown below fails.

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(enableKeyspaceEvents = EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_DEMAND)
public class RedisConfiguration {

    private DeloreanProperties deloreanProperties;

    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    private RedisConfigProperties redisConfigProperies;

    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public void setDeloreanProperties(DeloreanProperties deloreanProperties) {
        this.deloreanProperties = deloreanProperties;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setRedisConfigProperies(RedisConfigProperties redisConfigProperies) {
        this.redisConfigProperies = redisConfigProperies;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
        jedisClientConfiguration.connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
        jedisClientConfiguration.usePooling();

        if (Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(env -> (env.equalsIgnoreCase("deployed")))) {
            jedisClientConfiguration.useSsl();
        }

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName(redisConfigProperies.getHost());
        configuration.setPort(redisConfigProperies.getPort());
        configuration.setPassword(redisConfigProperies.getPassword());
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration, jedisClientConfiguration.build());
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        container.setTaskExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(deloreanProperties.getListenExecutorFixedThreadPool()));
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener messageListener() {
        KeyExpirationEventMessageListener messageListener = new KeyExpirationEventMessageListener(redisContainer());
        messageListener.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
        return messageListener;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the question Mota, as my team ran into the same issue and the documentation you posted was very useful.

After doing some research, I found a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-505) related where they have already addressed the problem in this [Git PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/pull/202)

As you stated before, the issue is that the listener tries to get and modify some parameters of the Redis node and AWS Elasticache does not allow the CONFIG command.

- Following this [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/repository/configuration/EnableRedisRepositories.java#L170) in their code, you can disable the listener from running these CONFIG commands by initializing an empty string for the `keyspaceNotificationsConfigParameter` in your @EnableRedisRepositories
- Remember to also create a new Elasticache [parameter group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Redis.html), where you set the `notify-keyspace-events` to AKE, and update your Redis node with the new parameter group

After the above changes, we are seeing no issues and the listener is working as intended.

Comment: I tried this. I am not getting error during startup  But it didnt cleanup indexes created by spring-data-redis. Do you have any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks!
Couple of points for more clarity:
 - Annotation "@EnableRedisRepositories(keyspaceNotificationsConfigParameter="")" to disable.
- If you are interested only in TTL expiry then just set "notify-keyspace-events" as "Ex"

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there is not a whole lot one can do about this. Here is an [info block in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/).

*The keyspace notification message listener alters notify-keyspace-events settings in Redis, if those are not already set. Existing settings are not overridden, so you must set up those settings correctly (or leave them empty). Note that CONFIG is disabled on AWS ElastiCache, and enabling the listener leads to an error.*

Comment: this is missing the last bit from the docs "to work around this behavior, set the keyspaceNotificationsConfigParameter parameter to an empty string. This prevents CONFIG command usage. "