# The RedisCommandExecutionException, ERR unknown command `CONFIG`, with args beginning with: `GET`, `notify-keyspace-events`

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

It's a simple project localhost in spring Boot, Java 11 Correto and everything is configured automatically using the spring-boot-starter-data-redis module. It has a postGres database. But I get failure when running the spring boot app.

dependency project pom.xml

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <apache-cxf-version>3.4.4</apache-cxf-version>
        <org.apache.tiles.version>2.2.2</org.apache.tiles.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
        <org.hibernate-jpamodelgen.version>4.3.11.Final</org.hibernate-jpamodelgen.version>
        <jasperreports.version>6.3.0</jasperreports.version>
        <batik-bridge.version>1.8</batik-bridge.version>
        <xmlgraphics-commons.version>2.1</xmlgraphics-commons.version>
        <jasperreports-plugin.version>2.3</jasperreports-plugin.version>
    </properties>   

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring depencencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

    <!-- boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

redis configuration

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class RedisConfig extends RedisHttpSessionConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public ConfigureRedisAction configureRedisAction() {
        return ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP;
    }

}
```

Properties file:

```
spring:
  data:
  redis:
    host: master.des-upf-redis-cluster.wvvha4.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com
    username: ${redis.server.user}
    password: ${redis.server.password}
    port: 6379
    timeout: 3600
    ssl:
      enabled: true
```

Locally it does not start due to a Redis configuration problem

when I run spring boot app, I get this following runtime error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.6)

2024-03-21 17:17:05.565  INFO 7508 --- [           main] edu.upf.CarrecsApplication               : Starting CarrecsApplication using Java 11.0.16 on WS142676 with PID 7508 (C:\workspacesAWS\uac-gid-carrecsj2ee\target\classes started by u89047 in C:\workspacesAWS\uac-gid-carrecsj2ee)
2024-03-21 17:17:05.569  INFO 7508 --- [           main] edu.upf.CarrecsApplication               : The following 1 profile is active: "DES"
2024-03-21 17:17:07.028  INFO 7508 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2024-03-21 17:17:07.031  INFO 7508 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-03-21 17:17:07.723  INFO 7508 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 682 ms. Found 12 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-03-21 17:17:07.736  INFO 7508 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2024-03-21 17:17:07.738  INFO 7508 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-03-18 12:26:30.932  INFO 11416 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface edu.upf.unipersonals.repository.AbsenciaRepository. If you want this repository to be a Redis repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.KeyValueRepository.
2024-03-21 17:17:07.801  INFO 7508 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 54 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2024-03-21 17:17:08.253  INFO 7508 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bdcba1f9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2024-03-21 17:17:08.328  INFO 7508 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2024-03-21 17:17:08.657  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-03-21 17:17:08.671  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-03-21 17:17:08.671  INFO 7508 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.60]
2024-03-21 17:17:09.106  INFO 7508 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-03-21 17:17:09.129  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/carrecs]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-03-21 17:17:09.129  INFO 7508 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3472 ms
2024-03-21 17:17:09.836  INFO 7508 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-03-21 17:17:10.776  INFO 7508 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-03-21 17:17:10.859  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-03-21 17:17:10.935  INFO 7508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.7.Final
2024-03-21 17:17:11.165  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2024-03-21 17:17:11.418  INFO 7508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2024-03-21 17:17:12.689  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2024-03-21 17:17:12.882  INFO 7508 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-03-21 17:17:12.921  WARN 7508 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-03-21 17:17:13.677  WARN 7508 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 39b68c00-b423-4f90-84fe-2915b4ed1819

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2024-03-21 17:17:13.791  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2024-03-21 17:17:13.813  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will not secure any request
2024-03-21 17:17:15.185  WARN 7508 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR unknown command `CONFIG`, with args beginning with: `GET`, `notify-keyspace-events`, 
2024-03-21 17:17:15.188  INFO 7508 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-03-21 17:17:15.191  INFO 7508 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-03-21 17:17:15.436  INFO 7508 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-03-21 17:17:15.579  INFO 7508 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-03-21 17:17:15.594  INFO 7508 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-21 17:17:15.612 ERROR 7508 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR unknown command `CONFIG`, with args beginning with: `GET`, `notify-keyspace-events`, 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at edu.upf.CarrecsApplication.main(CarrecsApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR unknown command `CONFIG`, with args beginning with: `GET`, `notify-keyspace-events`, 
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:52) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:272) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.await(LettuceConnection.java:1063) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.lambda$doInvoke$4(LettuceConnection.java:920) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceInvoker$Synchronizer.invoke(LettuceInvoker.java:673) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceInvoker$DefaultSingleInvocationSpec.get(LettuceInvoker.java:589) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceServerCommands.getConfig(LettuceServerCommands.java:177) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.getConfig(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:1674) ~[spring-data-redis-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.getNotifyOptions(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:74) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.configure(ConfigureNotifyKeyspaceEventsAction.java:55) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:333) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR unknown command `CONFIG`, with args beginning with: `GET`, `notify-keyspace-events`, 
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:147) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:116) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:120) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:111) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.complete(CommandWrapper.java:63) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:746) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:681) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:598) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.8.RELEASE.jar:6.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1372) ~[netty-handler-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235) ~[netty-handler-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1284) ~[netty-handler-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279) ~[netty-codec-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496) ~[netty-transport-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.75.Final.jar:4.1.75.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

My by I need some custom redis configuration to avoid calling CONFIG command? Or my be some other solution?

Comment: they say [it happens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36180380/175554) if the redis server is too old